# TinyMCE Image Tools Not Working

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I cannot seem to get the imagetools plugin to load with TinyMCE 4.2.5. I have downloaded TinyMCE 4.2.5 and installed it in my root site `/tinymce`.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="~/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ]
    });

</script>
```

Yet, when I paste an image into the editor, click on it, there are no image tools. I've verified the `imagetools` plugin exists in in the `plugins` directory and there are no errors in the browser console when the editor loads. It is like the feature is simply disabled.

I've also tried this with 4.2.5. I've tried this with Firefox and Chrome. It simply doesn't work.

This is what it supposed to do:

http://ephox.com/resources/blog/tinymce-4.2-released#.Vgg9cJeTQ0w

Comment: can you provide an updated link? - its 404ing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the image tools will only load if your image is loading from the same domain as the TinyMCE script does.

Here's some more information directly from Ephox:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=36139